# TypeError: not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'float'

Tags: python, neat, flappy-bird-clone

I am doing flappyBird game with neat from Tech with Tim tutorial and I created `self.type` inside Bird Class which means that bird is controllable by keyboard input or neat class, but I am getting this error after finish last generation:

```
     C:/Users/papadi166/Documents/MEGAsync/AppDev/FlappyBird/main.py:185: DeprecationWarning: an integer is required (got type float).  Implicit conversion to integers using __int__ is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version of Python.
  new_rect = rotated_image.get_rect(center = image.get_rect(topleft = topleft).center)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/papadi166/Documents/MEGAsync/AppDev/FlappyBird/main.py", line 393, in <module>
    run(config_path, genome_path="dict.pickle")
  File "C:/Users/papadi166/Documents/MEGAsync/AppDev/FlappyBird/main.py", line 364, in run
    winner = p.run(main, 2)
  File "C:\Users\papadi166\PycharmProjects\FlappyBird\venv\lib\site-packages\neat\population.py", line 99, in run
    if best is None or g.fitness > best.fitness:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'float'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

before i added this code to population.py:

```
        self.population = fitness_function(list(iteritems(self.population)), self.config)
        self.species.species[1].members = self.population
```

I got this error after finish one generation:
if best is None or g.fitness > best.fitness:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'float'

I understand that there is something wrong with loaded winner object, but I dont' know how to fix that in my code..

```
class Bird:
    IMGS = BIRD_IMGS
    P_IMGS = PLAYER_BIRD_IMGS
    MAX_ROTATION = 25
    ROT_VEL = 20
    ANIMATION_TIME = 5
    
    
    def __init__(self, x, y, t):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.tilt = 0
        self.tick_count = 0
        self.vel = 0
        self.height = self.y
        self.img_count = 0
        self.p_img = self.P_IMGS[0]
        self.img = self.IMGS[0]
        self.type = t
        
    def jump(self):
        self.vel = -10.5
        self.tick_count = 0
        self.height = self.y
    
    def move(self):
        self.tick_count +=1
        
        d = self.vel * (self.tick_count) + 0.5 * (3) * (self.tick_count)**2
        
        if d >= 16:
            d = (d/abs(d)) * 16
        if d < 0:
            d -= 2
        
        self.y = self.y + d
        
        if d < 0 or self.y < self.height + 50:
            if self.tilt < self.MAX_ROTATION:
                self.tilt = self.MAX_ROTATION
        else:
            if self.tilt > -90:
                self.tilt -= self.ROT_VEL
                
    def draw(self, win):
        self.img_count += 1

        if self.type == 0:
            if self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME:
                self.img = self.IMGS[0]
            elif self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME*2:
                self.img = self.IMGS[1]
            elif self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME*3:
                self.img = self.IMGS[2]
            elif self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME*4:
                self.img = self.IMGS[1]
            elif self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME*4 + 1:
                self.img = self.IMGS[0]
                self.img_count = 0

            if self.tilt <= -80:
                self.img = self.IMGS[1]
                self.img_count = self.ANIMATION_TIME*2

            blitRotateCenter(win, self.img, (self.x, self.y), self.tilt)


        if self.type == 1:
            if self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME:
                self.img = self.P_IMGS[0]
            elif self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME * 2:
                self.img = self.P_IMGS[1]
            elif self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME * 3:
                self.img = self.P_IMGS[2]
            elif self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME * 4:
                self.img = self.P_IMGS[1]
            elif self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME * 4 + 1:
                self.img = self.P_IMGS[0]
                self.img_count = 0

            if self.tilt <= -80:
                self.img = self.P_IMGS[1]
                self.img_count = self.ANIMATION_TIME * 2

            blitRotateCenter(win, self.p_img, (self.x, self.y), self.tilt)

    def get_mask(self):
        if self.type == 0:
            return pygame.mask.from_surface(self.img)
        elif self.type == 1:
            return pygame.mask.from_surface(self.p_img)

def main(genomes, config):

    """
    We need to keep track of neural network that controls each bird, because these genomes when they come in
    are really just a bunch of neural networks that are gonna control each of our birds, I need to keep track of the bird
    that that neural networks controlling so where that position is in the screen and I need to keep track of our genomes so
    that I actually change their fitness based on you know for they move or if they hit a pipe or if they do all this stuff
    so i do three lists to do this maybe not the most efficient way but should work fine
    """
    global GEN
    GEN += 1
    nets = []
    birds = []
    ge = []
    # Change bird = Bird(230, 350) to

    x = 0
    for _, g in genomes:
        if (x < len(genomes) -1) :
            net = neat.nn.FeedForwardNetwork.create(g, config)
            nets.append(net)
            birds.append(Bird(230, 350, 0))
            g.fitness = 0
            ge.append(g)
            x += 1
        if (x == len(genomes) -1):
            net = neat.nn.FeedForwardNetwork.create(g, config)
            nets.append(net)
            birds.append(Bird(230, 350, 1))
            g.fitness = 0
            ge.append(g)
            x += 1

    base = Base(730)
    pipes = [Pipe(600)]
    win = pygame.display.set_mode((WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT))
    run = True
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    score = 0

    while run:
        clock.tick(30)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    for bird in birds:
                        if bird.type == 1:
                            bird.jump()


        pipe_ind = 0
        if len(birds) > 0:
            if len(pipes) > 1 and birds[0].x > pipes[0].x + pipes[0].PIPE_TOP.get_width():
                pipe_ind = 1
        else:
            run = False
            break

        for x, bird in enumerate(birds):
            bird.move()
            ge[x].fitness += 0.1

            output = nets[x].activate((bird.y, abs(bird.y - pipes[pipe_ind].height), abs(bird.y - pipes[pipe_ind].bottom)))

            if output[0] > 0.5:
                if bird.type != 1:
                    bird.jump()

        #bird.move()
        add_pipe = False
        rem = []
        
        for pipe in pipes:
            for x, bird in enumerate(birds):
                # indent only this collision if becouse the rest of code don't have to be running at this for loop.
                if pipe.collide(bird):
                    ge[x].fitness -= 1 # Every time a bird hits a pipe is gonna have one removed from its fitness score
                    birds.pop(x)
                    nets.pop(x)
                    ge.pop(x)


                #Change bird.x to birds[0]... OR NOT..  better put that function into this for loop, because mian will runs 50 times so caling birds[0] 50 times isn't.. IDK. Efficient?
                if not pipe.passed and pipe.x < bird.x:
                    pipe.passed = True
                    add_pipe = True

            if pipe.x + pipe.PIPE_TOP.get_width() < 0:
                rem.append(pipe)

            pipe.move()

        if add_pipe:
            score += 1
            for g in ge:
                g.fitness += 5
            pipes.append(Pipe(700))

        for r in rem:
            pipes.remove(r)
        for x, bird in enumerate(birds):
            if bird.y + bird.img.get_height() >= 730 or bird.y < 0:
                birds.pop(x)
                nets.pop(x)
                ge.pop(x)

        base.move()
        draw_window(win, birds, pipes, base, score, GEN)

        if score >= 50:
            for x, bird in enumerate(birds):
                # indent only this collision if becouse the rest of code don't have to be running at this for loop.
                ge[x].fitness -= 1  # Every time a bird hits a pipe is gonna have one removed from its fitness score
                birds.pop(x)
                nets.pop(x)
                ge.pop(x)

def run(config_path, genome_path="dict.pickle"):
    import pickle
    genomes = []
    # Load the configuration
    config = neat.config.Config(neat.DefaultGenome, neat.DefaultReproduction,
                                neat.DefaultSpeciesSet, neat.DefaultStagnation, config_path)
    # Setup population
    p = neat.Population(config)

    #Set the output that we gonna see
    p.add_reporter(neat.StdOutReporter(True))
    stats = neat.StatisticsReporter()
    p.add_reporter(stats)

    # Set the fitness funnction ( This func. runs main func. 50 times and pass it all of the genoms so                                                                                   like that population current generation populations  )


    winner = p.run(main, 2)

    with open("dict.pickle", "wb") as infile:
        pickle.dump(winner, infile)
        infile.close()

    # Unpickle saved winner
    with open(genome_path, "rb") as infile:
        genome = pickle.load(infile)

    # Convert loaded genome into required data structure
    genomes = [(1, genome)]
    type = "test"
    # Call game with only the loaded genome
    main(genomes, config)
    print("LOL")
  
if __name__ == '__main__':
    local_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    config_path = os.path.join(local_dir, "config-feedforward.txt")
    run(config_path, genome_path="dict.pickle")
```

Comment: "if best is None or g.fitness > best.fitness: TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'float'" Okay, so what do you think this error means? Did you try looking at the part of the code *when and where the error occurs*? Did you try to check what `best` and `g`  are equal to? Are they what you expected? If not, can you explain that?

Comment: Anyway, showing us the entire code of your program is not helpful. There is way too much code to look at for the question, and almost all of it will be irrelevant.

Comment: Agree with Karl. It seems like you don't expect g to be None, but that is what is happening. So trace back g to see where it comes from, so you can see if it is set to None unexpectedly or if it never receives a value in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

For me, Declaring `ge[x].fitness` in a for loop before worked.

```py
# put this above the other for loops
for x, bird in enumerate(birds):
    ge[x].fitness = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact reason but for me it caused by number of hidden neurons.
I have 4 inputs and 5 output neurons. The number of my hidden neurons are 3 and it works. But when I change it to 10 it gives the same error. So you might want to change the number of your hidden neurons from config file.